# PictureBox Won't move on KeyDown when I Instantiate it's Form

Tags: vb.net

I'm creating a game where if the user pressed a key on a keyboard the picture box will move from a specific direction. I created  a class that handles the movement of the Picturebox when the user press the arrow keys. Which is This But the PictureBox don't move to the Right

```
Public Class movement

    Public Function right() As Action

        Dim myform As New Form3()
        myform.PictureBox1.Left += 1
        Return right
    End Function
End Class
```

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
Public Class Form3

    Public Sub Form3_KeyDown1(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
        Dim r As New movement

        Select Case e.KeyCode

            Case Keys.Right
                r.right()

        End Select
    End Sub


End Class
```

But when I call the Form3 Directly on the Class movement, The PictureBox Move from the Right. The reason why I instantiating a Form Because I will be using a some frames or a lot of picture box from different forms.

```
Public Class movement

    Public Function right() As Action


        Form3.PictureBox1.Left += 1
        Return right
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: You're creating a new instance of `Form3` each time while a key is down but also you're not displaying it.

Comment: So, What should the code look like I don't have an Idea

Comment: If you want to move a `PictureBox` in external `Form` you need to have an instance of that `Form` stored, for example in a private field.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Hello Sir John Saunders, Thanks for your help, by the way i tried your code but still, it was the picture box wont move

Answer (score 0):

Finally I wrote an example for you.

```
Public Class FormTarget
    Friend Sub LeftMovePictureBox(Optional ByVal offset As Integer = 1)
        PictureBox1.Left += offset
    End Sub
    Friend Sub TopMovePictureBox(Optional ByVal offset As Integer = 1)
        PictureBox1.Top += offset
    End Sub
End Class
```

And the controller:

```
Public Class FormController
    ReadOnly _formTarget As New FormTarget

    Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(e As EventArgs)
        _formTarget.Show()
        MyBase.OnLoad(e)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnClosing(e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs)
        _formTarget.Close()
        MyBase.OnClosing(e)
    End Sub

    Private Sub FormController_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
        Dim speed As Double = 1D
        If e.Modifiers = Keys.Control Then
            speed = 10D
        End If
        Select Case e.KeyValue
            Case Keys.Right
                _formTarget.LeftMovePictureBox(1 * speed)
            Case Keys.Left
                _formTarget.LeftMovePictureBox(-1 * speed)
            Case Keys.Up
                _formTarget.TopMovePictureBox(-1 * speed)
            Case Keys.Down
                _formTarget.TopMovePictureBox(1 * speed)
        End Select
    End Sub
End Class
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Hello Guys Thank's for your help, by the way dbvega I'm still confused on your code. I don't know where is my Form3 here and also my class which makes my picturebox move

Comment: @JohnPerez the `FormController` is the class for movement and the `FormTarget` is your "`Form3`".